# Deactivate service worker after unregister

Tags: javascript, typescript, service-worker

For a project I'm working on I've implemented a service worker which comes active after testMode=true is put into the url. However I noticed that once testMode=true is removed from the url, the service worker is still active and is used which is not what I want.

This is the page in which it's registered:

```
class TestMode {
    public init(): void {
        const baseUrl = hosts.getHost(HostNames.Planner);
        const countryCode = localeService.getLocale();

    if (!this.isEnabled()) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
            for(const registration of registrations) {

                if (registration?.active?.scriptURL === `${baseUrl}/worker.${countryCode}.min.js`) {
                    registration.unregister().then()
                    {
                        registration.update();
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        return;
    }

    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
        debug.log(__filename, 'Browser does not support service workers');
        return;
    }

    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(`${baseUrl}/worker.${countryCode}.min.js`)
        .then(this.handleRegistration)
        .catch((error) => {
            throw new Error('Service Worker registration failed: ' + error.message);
        });
}

private handleRegistration(registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration): void {
    registration.update();

    debug.log(__filename, 'Registration successful, scope is: ' + registration.scope);
}

public isEnabled(): boolean {
    return locationService.hasParam('testMode');
}
}

export const testMode = new TestMode();
```

Now what I tried to do was to simply unregister it like so:

```
    if (!this.isEnabled()) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
            for(const registration of registrations) {

                if (registration?.active?.scriptURL === `${baseUrl}/worker.${countryCode}.min.js`) {
                    registration.unregister().then()
                    {
                        registration.update();
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        return;
    }
```

This does unregister it, but the service worker is still active until I refresh the page again, is there a way to deactivate straight after the unregister without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score -1):

I've added window.location.reload so it now reads like so:

```
if (!this.isEnabled()) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
        for (const registration of registrations) {
            if (registration?.active?.scriptURL === `${baseUrl}/worker.${countryCode}.min.js`) {
                registration.unregister();
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });

    return;
}
```

This actually seems to work well for me